# Javascript : how to cancel the execution of a script

Tags: javascript, ajax, canvas

I have a web page with a canvas and 2 href links to run an application (application 1 or application 2) in canvas, as follow :

```
<canvas id="canvas" style="border:solid black 1px;"></canvas>

<a href="javascript:runApplication('application-1.js')">Run application 1 on canvas</a>

<br><a href="javascript:runApplication('application-2.js')">Run application 2 on canvas</a>
```

When you click on a href link, you run the runApplication() function, the parameter is the js script for application.

Here the runApplication() function :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

//Function to run application :
function runApplication(jsFile)
{
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
       if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200)
       {
           jsScript = xhr.responseText; 

           //Run the js script of application on canvas :
           eval(jsScript);
       }
    } 

    //Retrieve js script of application :
    xhr.open("POST", jsFile, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.send("");
}

</script>
```

In this function, when the js script of application is retrieved by ajax, he run the js script with eval().

Here the application-1.js :

```
//Application object :
application = {

    //Initialization :
    "init" : function()
    {   
        //Get canvas element :
        application.canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        application.canvas.context = application.canvas.getContext("2d");   

        //Drawing on canvas :
        setInterval(application.draw, 30);      
    }, 

    //Method for drawing :
    "draw" : function()
    {
        //Clear canvas :
        application.canvas.context.clearRect(0, 0, application.canvas.width, application.canvas.height);        

        //Draw text on canvas :

        application.canvas.context.fillStyle = "blue";

        application.canvas.context.font = "normal normal 15px sans-serif";

        application.canvas.context.fillText("Application 1", 50, 50);   
    }
};

application.init();
```

Here the application-2.js :

```
//Application object :
application = {

    //Initialization :
    "init" : function()
    {   
        //Get canvas element :
        application.canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        application.canvas.context = application.canvas.getContext("2d");   

        //Drawing on canvas :
        setInterval(application.draw, 30);      
    }, 

    //Method for drawing :
    "draw" : function()
    {
        //Clear canvas :
        application.canvas.context.clearRect(0, 0, application.canvas.width, application.canvas.height);        

        //Draw text on canvas :

        application.canvas.context.fillStyle = "red";

        application.canvas.context.font = "normal normal 15px sans-serif";

        application.canvas.context.fillText("Application 2", 50, 100);  
    }
};

application.init();
```

So when you click on the first href link to run application 1 on the canvas, it works (application 1 text is displayed on canvas).

Afterwards, when you click on the second href link to run application 2 on the canvas, the application 2 is run in the canvas (application 2 text is displayed on canvas) but the application 1 is still run on canvas, so it's a problem because I want to cancel the execution of application-1 script and run application 2 instead of application 1.

So how to cancel the execution of a js script (cancel application-1.js) ?

Comment: Do you need to use eval or could the application scripts be functions?

Comment: Yes because there are a lots of applications (more 100 js script), so put 100 codes in the same web page is very heavy for browser and for user.

Comment: You can always put them in .js files and load the Javascript files as needed.  This would give you more control than using eval

Comment: That's what I do with ajax, loading the javascript file chosen by the user, but I don't know how to erase the execution of a js application when the user click on an another application.